# VBA(excel) numbers as string comparation

Tags: excel, vba

How to compare numbers as string? 
I want to compare f.ex. 2 and 10. When i sort them in Excel in ascending order 2 is before 10, but when i compare in VBA those two 10 seems to be lower number than 2. I'm using strcomp function. I need to compare them as strings beacuse it's a part of bigger program that's searching for the identical strings in excel columns. Strings can be normal strings, numbers and number-ish strings as "12-131xxx".

Comment: The only way to do this is to pad them with leading zeros or treat numbers as numbers. Can you post your code? It's possible there is a work-around such as [using a regular expression](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22542834/4088852) instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mnich, with *StrComp*, either **vbBinaryCompare** or **vbTextCompare** will give you the returns you're currently getting. When Excel sorts numbers/integers, it sorts as you would expect, but when sorting numbers as strings, it uses a textual comparison; so all numbers starting with 1, even 111, will be ranked lower than 2. As [Comintern](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4088852/comintern) mentions, you have to add leading zeros to get away with this.

Or, perhaps, you replied one number comparison before you ranked the strings, you could try a Function to extract the numbers, then let that weigh your decision:

```
'pass in array from main stuff
Function StackOverflow(arr())

Dim arr_NewStr() As String
Dim x As Integer
Dim i As Integer
ReDim arr_NewStr(1 To UBound(arr))

x = 1

For i = 1 To UBound(arr)
    Do
        If IsNumeric(Mid(arr(i), x, 1)) Then
            arr_NewStr = arr_NewStr & Mid(arr(i), x, 1)
        End If
        x = x + 1
    Loop Until x = Len(arr(i))
Next

'clean up
x = vbEmpty: i = vbEmpty

'pass somewhere, or make "arr" public
```

End Function